# Cordova Facebook plugin return wrong user id

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins

i'm using Cordova Facebook Plugin that I downloaded from https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin. I already installed and config plugin on iOS app.

when I use

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login( ['public_profile, email, user_friends'], 
            function(response){
                alert(JSON.stringify(response))
            }, 
            function(error){
                //alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

when I check return data, I realize that it return me the wrong **facebook user id**.

user id that return to me is **10200666146253500** which is not me user id.

when I use that user_id to function

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api("10200666146253500/", [], function(result){
                                var fb_user = { fbid : $scope.fbid,
                                                email : result.email,
                                                firstname : result.first_name,
                                                lastname : result.last_name,
                                                gender : result.gender }

                            });
```

It return me an error like this user_id doesn't have profile.

I don't know this problem is about the Facebook update api version? or I did something wrong.

Please give me any suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Are you login-in using this profile - `https://www.facebook.com/thegiffary` ?

Comment: yes, that is my account

Comment: So if you are login-in using above account, user-id returned is right. you can try `https://www.facebook.com/10200666146253500`